# Html 5 fullscreen video overflows by a few pixels on mobile devices

Tags: css, html, video, responsive-design, fullscreen

Hope this can be solved!

I have created a website with a fixed fullscreen video `header` and it works fine on my monitor but once i try to view on any smaller screens the video overflows by a few pixels - adding a scroll bar to the bottom of the screen.

I have tried various methods but it still adds the extra annoying pixels!

My code for the video div is as follows

```
video {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px; /* fixed to left. Replace it by right if you want.*/
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background: url(../img/carousel-1.jpg) center center no-repeat scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
.header-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    position: relative;
}
.video-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(../img/carousel-1.jpg) center center no-repeat scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
 @media(max-width:1024px) {
#buttonbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 15%;
    right: 15%;
    z-index: 20;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
    text-align: center;
}
}
#play {
    border: none;
    height: 102px;
    width: 204px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url(../img/play-pause.png) center center no-repeat scroll;
    opacity: .8;
}
#play:focus {
    opacity: .5;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#play:active {
}
#pause {
    background: url(../img/vid-play.png) center center no-repeat scroll;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
 @media(max-width:767px) {
.hidden-767 {
    display: none;
}
}
```

Here is the test website
http://www.lightcorp93.com/test/index.html

Thanks for your help

Comment: can you not just add `overflow: hidden;` to the div tag?

Comment: This code from bootstrap.css is causing the issue`.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}`

Comment: Problem is the row, as @James said

Answer (score 0):

Try `right:0` and remove `min-width`.

Comment: Unfortunately, its still does it. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

@James @Marcos Pérez Gude Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

It's probably not the prettiest fix but I created a new class called adjust, that had an attribute of margin-right:-13px.

I applied to the individual rows that were causing the overflow and it's fixed it, I think!